# ScreenShots on Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, screenshot

I want to ScreenShot a certain windows and a certain part of my desktop from my Ubuntu and I don't know how.

<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> doesn't work.

<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> it works only when I screenshot all my displays and not only the one from my virtual machine where I need.

I want something that can crop exactly the part I need. 
Something more alike to snipping tool from Windows.

Comment: Could you please explain what you meant by "<PrtScr> doesn't work"? How exactly does it fail? What about <Fn>+<PrtScr>?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. He wants something like snipper in windows.

Comment: Use screenshot application with third option. You don't have to install anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (in terminal a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shutter/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

Open Shutter by simply typing `Shutter` in the terminal.

Comment: Alternatively, download Shutter from the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Comment: I don't have Ubuntu software center. Does it work if I install it from the terminal?

Comment: yes. install it by typping the next command: sudo apt-get install software-center

Answer (score 0):

I have Mint 18.2 running on Ubuntu 16.04 and use `xfce4-screenshooter`, which should be preinstalled.
Simply execute from Terminal, then choose options in gui.
Available options are:
 - whole screen
 - active window
 - choose area
 - record cursor
If not preinstalled, in Terminal do:
`sudo apt-get install xfce4-screenshooter`

Comment: How can you have "*Mint 18.2 running on Ubuntu 16.04*"?! Both are distros. And no, `xfce4-screenshooter` is not usually pre-installed unless you have Xfce DE in particular.

Comment: @pomsky I guess “running on” means “based on”.